# Where are the technical documents about android enterprise?

Tags: android-enterprise

I'm looking for some solutions about managing a fleet of mobile devices, but I found that all the documents is about how to communicate with androidmanagement.googleapis.com.

But I want to know more about how to communicate with the device directly.

Basically my question:

Is it possible to self host a androidmanagement.googleapis.com service?